# Vaadin elements vaadin-grid custom renderer in API 2+

Tags: javascript, vaadin, polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid, vaadin-elements

I'm almost done in porting a couple of projects based on vaadin elements 
 [vaadin-grid](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid)
from API 1.x to the latest version but I've not found examples or documentation about how to assign a custom renderer to a column.

For example in  [main.js](https://github.com/rondinif/vaadin-grid-rest/blob/master/src/main/resources/public/main.js) I can't figure out how to port in API 2+ the following:

```
  grid.columns[2].renderer = function (cell) {
    cell.element.innerHTML = '';
    var progressBar = document.createElement('progress');
    progressBar.setAttribute('value', ((statuses.indexOf(cell.data) + 1) / statuses.length).toString());
    cell.element.appendChild(progressBar);
  };
```

The specific problem in here is that in API 2+ `columns` are `undefined`

Is it possible to assing custom rendering behavoir to a `vaadin-grid-column`?

NB: this question is not about `vaadin framework` but about [vaadin elements](https://vaadin.com/elements)

Debug session looking for something may help such as `TemplateRenderer` or similar but I found nothing until now:
[image: 20171118-debug-renderer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS API is significantly changed from v1 to v2, and there’s no longer a `columns` object. Instead, if you want to configure columns using JS, you need to modify the properties of the `<vaadin-grid-column>` elements directly (you need to have a DOM reference).

For renderers specifically, you use regular HTML in the column template, as mentioned in [the migration guide](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/wiki/Migration-from-1.*-to-2.0#data-formatting) (the Wiki was closed for some reason, I just reopened it).

For your specific code example, it would translate to:

```
<vaadin-grid>
  <vaadin-grid-column>
    <template>
     <progress value="[[item.value]]"></progress>
    </template>
  </vaadin-grid-column>
</vaadin-grid>
```

Replace `item.value` with the correct property in your data object (or use a computed property if you need to transform the data somehow before passing it onto the `<progress>` element.

**Bonus:**

Have you considered using [`<vaadin-progress-bar>`](https://vaadin.com/elements/vaadin-progress-bar/html-examples/progress-bar-basic-demos) ;)

Valo theme demo: https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-valo-theme/2.0.0-alpha4/demo/progress-bars.html